# How can I hide the AJAX result when the corresponding checkbox is not selected?

Tags: ajax

```
1: <input class="category" type="checkbox" name="genre[]"
value="1" onchange="categoryCheckbox(1)"><br>
2: <input class="category" type="checkbox" name="genre[]"
value="2" onchange="categoryCheckbox(2)"><br>
3: <input class="category" type="checkbox" name="genre[]"
value="3" onchange="categoryCheckbox(3)"><br>
4: <input class="category" type="checkbox" name="genre[]"
value="4" onchange="categoryCheckbox(4)"><br>
5: <input class="category"type="checkbox" name="genre[]"
value="5" onchange="categoryCheckbox(5)"><br


<script>
 function categoryCheckbox(id) {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'admin/filtro/' + id,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
                response.forEach(element => {
                    $('#books').append(`<p>${element.title}</p>`);
                })
            }
        })
    } else $(this).hide();
  };
    </script>
```

If I select the checkbox with id 5, I want it to display the result of ajax 5.
If I select 4 and 5 it shows me both, but if I uncheck 4 it only shows me 5

Answer (score 0):

You actually try to hide the input in your else statement. Try to give the p-Tag you are appending an id and use the id as your jQuery selector in the else statement to hide the p-Tag corresponding to the unchecked checkbox.

Your remove call would in that case look somewhat like this:

```
$('#elem-1').remove();
```